# How to backup an entire Raspberry Pi TF card's filesystem into an image via Linux or Mac

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, backup

Raspberry pi easily suffer the sudden cutoff of power supply, which may lead to a system corruption or data losing. So, it is important to find some methods for the purpose of system backup.

I wish there exist some tools or scripts which can packet the entire  filesystem on TF card into an image. Then, when the system crashes and can't be repaired. I could restore it from these images. I feel that the images just act as snapshoots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dd` command to save sdcard to a file when the sdcard is not in use.

sample usage is

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/your/destination/image/file bs=8M
```

the bs parameter means block size, since the default block size just 512 bytes, the size is so small that reading/writing speed are slow.

and the image file can be compressed by gzip/bzip2/xz/... etc, i suggest use `man` command to get the details of command.

Comment: But, how can I restore it?

Comment: 'if' means input file and 'of' is output, so why not try 'man dd' ?